# Enviar datos según radio button seleccionado

Tags: html

Tengo varios radio button y necesito que cada radio envíe un dato a un submit, ya que necesito llenar una tabla con estos datos. El codigo de los radio button es este:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="rol">cliente</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="rol">supervisor</label>
    </div>
                
</div>
```

cuando retorno el request de mi formulario me imprime todos mis datos, pero en el apartado rol me imprime `"rol":"on"`

`{"_token":"AaYDVTgm4kEgwBu77J2cImxdoyrwsh4NZOX85o8h","name":"dsfsdfs","apellido_p":"sdfsdf","apellido_m":"asdas","rol":"on","username":"asdas","password":"asda"}`

¿Cómo puedo enviar los datos según esté seleccionado, por ejemplo `"rol":"cliente"`?

Comment: Tendrías que agregarle el atributo `value="cliente"` https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_radio.asp

Comment: Cada radio button debe de tener el atributo value="nombrre-del-campo" pero cada value debe de ser difefente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utiliza la propiedad value, revisa la documentación: [radio-button](https://www.htmlquick.com/es/reference/tags/input-radio.html)

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <div class="radio">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="rol" value="cliente">cliente</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="rol" value="supervisor">supervisor</label>
                </div>
                
                 </div>
```